# Need help with solving differential equation and plotting velocity as a function of forcing term magnitude

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I needed some help with plotting a velocity vs forcing term diagram for a chaotic oscillator on mathematica.

Basically, I have to solve the following differential equation

```
x''[t] + b x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 - f Cos[w t] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
 x[0] == 0
```

and plot the velocity of my solution for times in the interval [0,1000] in increments of 2*Pi
for different values of f.

That is, for each f in the interval [0,2] (in increments of .05), I will have approximately 150 velocity points, and I must plot all of these points on one graph.

I though about using a do loop and came up with something like

```
Remove["Global`*"]

b = .1;
w = 1;
Period = 1;
tstep = 2 Pi/Period;

Do[{Do[{data = 
     Table[Flatten[
       Evaluate[{f, 
         x'[t] /. 
          NDSolve[{x''[t] + b x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 - f Cos[w t] == 0,
             x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 1000}, 
           MaxSteps -> 59999]}]], {t, 0, 1000, tstep}]}, {t, 0, 1000, 
    1}]}, {f, 0, 2, .1}]
```

but had no luck.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your replacement rule, `x'[t] /. NDSolve[...]`, won't work because `NDSolve` returns `x[t] -> ...`, but `x'[t]` internally has the form `Derivative[1][x][t]` which is very different. (You can check this yourself by using `FullForm`.) Replacement rules replace exactly the form you tell it to, and it can require a lot of effort to have them do any sort of transformation beyond the basic. This one qualifies as beyond basic. In those cases, `FullForm` and `MatchQ` are indispensable for determining what will and won't work.

Comment: You're not supposed to remove your question once you have received an answer. I've rolled back your last edit in which you did this.

Comment: FP, is your update just to clarify the question, or are you hoping for a revised answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
b = .1;
w = 1;

sol := {f, 
  NDSolve[{x''[t] + b x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 - f Cos[w t] == 0, 
     x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> 59999][[1, 1, 2]]}

interpsols = Table[sol, {f, 0, 2, 0.1}];

ListPlot[Table[interpsols, {t, 0, 1000, 2 Pi}]]
```

---

#### The Explanation

First, let me focus on `sol`.  This is close to your own code (with a change) but refactored for clarity, rather than buried inside the loops.

- `sol :=` is equivalent to `SetDelayed[sol, ...`
- This holds the unevaluated definition that it is given on the right-hand-side
- The `NDSolve` operation is therefore not performed until `sol` is used somewhere

The change I made was to extract this portion from the result of `NDSolve`:

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t]
```

I do this with `Part`:  `NDSolve[...][[1, 1, 2]]`

It could also be done with `x[t] /. First @ NDSolve[...]`

This extracted portion is paired with the current value of `f` in a list: `{f, NDSolve[ ... }` so that later they can be plotted.

Now:

```
interpsols = Table[sol, {f, 0, 2, 0.1}];
```

builds a table of the changing value of `sol` as it globally changes the value of `f`.  This is where NDSolve is performed.

The result is a series of solutions for each value of `f` in this form:

```
{{0.,InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t]},
 {0.1,InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t]},
 {0.2,InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t]},
 {0.3,InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t]},
 {0.4,InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t]}
 ...
```

Finally:

```
ListPlot[Table[interpsols, {t, 0, 1000, 2 Pi}]]
```

creates a table by evaluating the entire series of results created above for globally changing values of `t`, and `ListPlot`s it.

There are a few things more I would like to say but I am out of time.  I will make a further edit in a few hours.

Comment: Yes, I think this fixes my problem.
Thanks you so much!

How does it work?

Comment: To honor his nickname, Mr. Wizard should answer -"It's magic"-

Comment: Haha, yes 
Also, why do the points have different colors?
Is it because they correspond to the same t value but different f values?

Comment: Two nits: `f` should be incremented by `0.05` and the OP asked for the velocity. The second nit is easily fixable by prepending `D[#, t]&@` in front of `NDSolve`. Otherwise, should work.

Comment: @Frustrated, the different colors are due to the fact that there are numerous different lists being plotted. Each one gets its own color.  This is "fixable" by setting `PlotStyle -> Black`, or any other color.

Comment: rcollyer, what does D[#, t]&@ do to NDSolve? and also to solve for velocity, I can simply solve my differential equation before I define soln and then assign x'[t] to the second component of soln right?

Comment: but oh, okay, the different colors makes sense now

Comment: oh, I think I see, your iteration of D[#, t]&@ tells mathematica to take the derivative of the NDSolve solution for each t value, thereby giving me the velocity at each point.

Also, if I do a listlineplot, I can see how my system changes with time for each f value, since each different line corresponds to the a set of points with the same f values but different time values right?

Comment: @Frustrated, see my comment on your question on why assigning it to `x'[t]` like you did won't work. Now, `D[#,t]&` is a pure function taking one argument which will replace the `Slot` (`#`) and returns the derivative (`D`) of that argument with respect to `t`. The `@` symbol allows you to apply functions in prefix form, i.e. `f @ t` is equivalent to `f[t]`, where `f` is a function. So, this tells Mathematica to take the derivative after it has solved the differential equation.

Comment: @Frustrated, yes, you are correct on your interpretation of the plot. You can also use the `Joined-> True` option to achieve the same effect. Note: the derivative must occur before `t` takes on a definite value, otherwise `D` generates an error. In the code above, this would occur within the first `Table` where `t` is not yet defined, so we're in good shape.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Congrats on 5000! Bumped you to yet another milestone.

Comment: @Frustrated the colors come from the multiple lists passed to `ListPlot`.  Alternatively to `PlotStyle -> Black` you could use this instead:  `ListPlot[Join @@ Table[interpsols, {t, 0, 1000, 2 Pi}]]`

Comment: Okay, I see
Also what does the [1,1,2] after the NDSolve function do?

Comment: @Frustrated as I said in my answer: "The change I made was to extract this portion from the result of `NDSolve` ... I do this with Part: `NDSolve[...][[1, 1, 2]]`" It works like this: `expr[[1, 1, 2]]` gives the second part of the first part of the first part of `expr`.  Or, another way, `expr[[1]]` gives the first part of `expr`, `expr[[1][[1]]` gives the first part of that, and expr[[1]][[1]][[2]] gives the second part of that.  This can be written using the compact form `expr[[1, 1, 2]]`.  See [the helps for Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) for more information.